# Installing fring on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Can anyone help installing fring on Windows 7? I have downloaded fring from the following link.
http://fring.en.softonic.com/pocketpc/download
When I install the fring, I get an error

```
Active sync cannot be found on this computer. Setup cannot continue and now will exit.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

well, the application file you've downloaded is a PC based installer for handheld devices (windows mobile or pocket pc) - it wants to use active-sync to get through to the handheld and install it there.

To date there is NO native fring for windows - people around use fring for android running in android emulator for PC. And, it works :-)